# Designing custom visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app

I'm new to salesforce development and I'm trying to design the page that look something like below and I'm using apex code to design.

PS: I'm new to SFD

the page looks like [image: this]

Create Page Name

---

here is what i have tried so far.

```
<apex:page >
<apex:form id="changeStatusForm">
<apex:pageBlock >

<apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="  Save  " action="{!save}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="  Cancel  " action="{!cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>

<table width="100%" border="1">
               <tr>
               <td>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Name1"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                <apex:outputLabel value="owner"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                <apex:outputLabel value="s date"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                <apex:outputLabel value="country"/>
                </td>                
                <td>
                <apex:outputLabel value="amount"/>
                </td>
                </tr>
</table>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>        
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with? Nesting two apex:pageBlockTables might be the way forward.

Comment: i'm unable to create/design the above page with visualforce

Answer (score 1):

The page you're looking to create will depend more on HTML than it will on Visualforce.  You'll need to set up the framework of your page in HTML, then each line item becomes a Visualforce repeat element.

If I were doing this, I'd create the whole page in HTML first with dummy data, make sure it works across the range of devices it's going to be displayed on, then add in the required Visualforce components.